# Rails: Is it a bad idea to put double-byte character inside a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I've learnt that you may define a Ruby source file as UTF-8 to be able to key inside it double-byte characters (e.g.: ¤) instead of their HTML code (e.g.: & curren;):

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class Price < ActiveRecord:Base
   def currency_symbol
       '¤'  
   end
end
```

Without the encoding statement, I would need to write '& curren;'.html_safe as the core of the method.
I don't like the later because it assume I'm writing HTML (I have Excel output in my app on top of HTML).

My question is: Is there any problems or performance hits I must be aware while doing this?

Note: Ruby 2.0 brings UTF-8 as the default encoding; does it mean all Ruby files will automatically support all those characters?

Character chart: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: it is, that should be handld by i18n

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the kind of thing that should go in the locales (`config/locales`). These are YAML files that define words and characters that will be used in the various parts of your application, including currency symbols. It also has the benefit of allowing you to easily introduce translations for other languages.

Take a look at the [ruby on rails guide for i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for more.

Comment: I understand your answer about i18n, but let say my character is i18n agnostic.

Comment: What character(s) are you trying to use?

Comment: Instead of using the HTML character codes, you can paste the actual unicode symbols into the locale YAML file.